# Are $lookups in mongodb Aggregate query performed serially or parallelly?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using multiple `$lookup` inside MongoDB Aggregate query, I want to know are these $lookup queries performed parallelly or serially?

Comment: **ALL** aggregation pipeline stage execution is of course **serial** and **in order**, which is of course part of the reason why pipelines are an array. I actually sense a "question within a question" here, so if you actually have something to ask about a particular piece of code then you should go ahead and ask it. A question on Stack Overflow is meant to be a "question" and not a "conversation", so open ended questions which tend lead to an "Okay, but now what about this case?" are discouraged, and you should fully describe an actual case rather than a general supposition.

Comment: Or are you asking about the actual "joins" themselves? In which case this is **one** query and not several as you might be supposing. Again, it's not really clear why you should care without context of code and what might not be happening as you expect in the question. So it's simply better to just ask that.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just wanted to ask because as I am doing two lookups which are independent of each other, that's why wanted to know whether they will be queried parallelly/serially, as of course parallelly would be better as both queries are independent.

Comment: Like I said, your're probably asking about "your code" but you did not include "your code" in the question. It's better to ask a direct question than a general concept. So just be direct in the future.